# Understanding Solid state relay specifications

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay, specifications

I've been looking for a solid state relay that can switch 240V from a 3.3V signal.

Looking at DigiKey, with a very large selection, I'm not sure how to filter my search (screenshot attached). How do I interpret the "Voltage Input" and "Voltage Load" criteria compared to the coil and switching voltage for regular relay ? (screenshot attached)

The names seem pretty self explanatory but I'm surprised there aren't any 3V DC controlled SSRs - hence the uncertainty

[image]

Comment: It looks to me that most or perhaps all of the ones that your search would yield will switch 240 V with a 3.3V signal. Pick one or several, download the spec sheets and see how the input voltage specification is described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3-32 is a very common input range, which means it will work with 3.3V drive.

If I search on "In stock", output type: AC, AC-DC or AC zero cross, and all with minimum input voltage up to 3V, and "output current" min 5A max 35A I get 122 results.

Comment: thanks ! when you say 3-32, is that the same as 3 ~ 32 DC ?

Comment: Yes, my tilda was temporarily out of service.

Comment: No worries thanks ! I misread the ~ myself... even on the data sheet and the component itself it is 3-32 so you were right

Comment: found this one thanks to you : https://www.digikey.fr/product-detail/fr/sensata-crydom/D2W203F/CC1118-ND/221811
Looks like a good candidate